# BigPicture app data Jira migrating from server to cloud

Tags: jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

we are moving, due to new Atlassian policy, from Jira Server to Jira Cloud - we didn't find any way to migrate BigPicture data (projects, settings) plugin to the Jira Cloud.

Does somebody face the same problem - is there any workaround solutions?